# NextJS - Cant fetching a Single Item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I can't fetch a Single Item, NextJS

```js
const PRODUCT_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/";

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(PRODUCT_API_BASE_URL);
    const data = await res.json();
    const paths = data.map(product => {
        return {
            params: {
                id: product.id.toString()
            }
        }
    })
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const id = context.params.id;
    const res = await fetch(PRODUCT_API_BASE_URL + id);
    const data = await res.json();

    return {
        props: { product: data }
    }
}

const ProductDetail = ({ product }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {product.nameProduct}
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductDetail
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name `id` does not match with `productId`. This should fix it:

> ```
> const paths = data.map(product => {
>     return {
>         params: {
>             productId: product.id.toString()
>         }
>     }
> })
> ```